# INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY,

Tags: apex, opportunity-lineitem, trigger

I am writing a trigger to insert the **`OpportunityLineItemSchedule`** and getting this error

> System.DmlException: Upsert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY, insufficient access rights on cross-reference id: []

```
trigger ProductScheduleTriggerBulk on OpportunityLineItem (after insert,before update) 
{
Date currentDate;
Decimal numberPayments;
Decimal paymentAmount;
Decimal totalPaid;
List<OpportunityLineItemSchedule> newScheduleObjects = new List<OpportunityLineItemSchedule>();

// For every OpportunityLineItem record, add its associated pricebook entry
// to a set so there are no duplicates.
Set<Id> pbeIds = new Set<Id>();
for (OpportunityLineItem oli : Trigger.new) 
    pbeIds.add(oli.pricebookentryid);

// Query the PricebookEntries for their associated info and place the results
// in a map.
Map<Id, PricebookEntry> entries = new Map<Id, PricebookEntry>(
    [select id, product2.IsActive from pricebookentry 
     where id in :pbeIds]);

 // For every OpportunityLineItem record, add its associated oppty
// to a set so there are no duplicates.
Set<Id> opptyIds = new Set<Id>();
for (OpportunityLineItem oli : Trigger.new) 
    opptyIds.add(oli.OpportunityId);

// Query the Opportunities for their associated info and place the results
// in a map.
Map<Id, Opportunity> Opptys = new Map<Id, Opportunity>(
    [select Id, CloseDate from Opportunity 
     where id in :opptyIds]);

 // Iterate through the changes
for (OpportunityLineItem item : trigger.new) {

      if(entries.get(item.pricebookEntryID).product2.IsActive == true) {
              //OK, we have an item that needs to be Auto Scheduled
              //Calculate the payment amount
              paymentAmount = item.TotalPrice;
              numberPayments = item.Quantity;
              paymentAmount = paymentAmount > 0 ? paymentAmount/numberPayments : 0;
              system.debug('nopayments' + numberPayments);
              //System.debug('    Base Monthly Amount = ' + paymentAmount);
              // Determine which date to use as the start date.         
              if (item.ServiceDate == NULL) {
                    currentDate = Opptys.get(item.OpportunityId).CloseDate;
                }
                else
                {
                  currentDate = item.ServiceDate;
                }
              totalPaid = 0;
              // Loop though the payments 
              for (Integer i = 1;i < numberPayments;i++) {
                    OpportunityLineItemSchedule s = new OpportunityLineItemSchedule();
                    s.Revenue = paymentAmount;
                    s.ScheduleDate = currentDate;
                    s.OpportunityLineItemId = item.id;
                    s.Type = 'Revenue';
                    newScheduleObjects.add(s); 
                    totalPaid = (totalPaid > 0 ? totalPaid + paymentAmount : 0);
                    currentDate = currentDate.addMonths(1); 
                    System.debug('********Date ' + currentDate + ' Amount ' + paymentAmount);
                    }
              //Now Calulate the last payment!
              paymentAmount = item.TotalPrice > 0 ? (item.TotalPrice - totalPaid):0;
              OpportunityLineItemSchedule s = new OpportunityLineItemSchedule();
              s.Revenue = paymentAmount;
              s.ScheduleDate = currentDate;
              s.OpportunityLineItemId = item.id;
              s.Type = 'Revenue'; 
              newScheduleObjects.add(s);               
              System.debug(' LAST PAYMENT ');
              System.debug('********Date ' + currentDate + ' Amount ' + paymentAmount);

    } // End If Auto_Schedule_Revenue
  } // End For OpportunityLineItem    
 if (newScheduleObjects.size() > 0) {
  try {
  system.debug('list data = '+newScheduleObjects);
    upsert newScheduleObjects;
     } catch (System.DmlException e) {
      for (Integer ei = 0; ei < e.getNumDml(); ei++) {
          System.debug(e.getDmlMessage(ei));
      } 
      //
      // There should be something here to alert the user what failed!
      //
    } // End Catch
    } // End If greater than 0    
   } // End Trigger ProductScheduleTriggerBulk
```

Comment: check for the field and profile permission.

Comment: I am logged in as system admin...

Comment: Is the upsert triggering any other record to be updated? E.g. opportunitylineitem, opportunity, etc?

Comment: opportunitylineitemSchedule

Comment: yes I understand. I'm looking for any updates to other objects, as it doesn't look like the error is coming from this upsert but more likely from another action that is a consequence of this one.. Would it e.g. be possible to include a larger part of the debug logs so we can see exactly where it goes wrong?

Comment: @Guy error is solved I forgot to check the checkbox in Product Schedules Settings..

Comment: ok nice, happens to the best :-)

Comment: but now new error is coming :
first error: FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, field integrity exception: Type (schedule type must match existing schedules)

Comment: @Anzar - Can you check what value is getting assigned in revenue field? As the value can't be null when your schedule type is revenue.

Comment: @SnehaPatil yes value is coming in revenue...